# Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libffi.5.dylib but I'm using homebrew

Tags: ruby, homebrew, ffi

I'm trying to run guard on Mac OS X Lion(XCode 4.3+OSX GCC Installer+Homebrew)

Error message:

```
Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libffi.5.dylib
```

I have no `/opt/local` directory since I'm not using MacPorts but Homebrew

I tried `brew install libffi`, which was successful, but the gem still doesn't work.

I also have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the gem without success.

Problem is also occurring on OSX 10.9 (Mavericks) with `apple-gcc42` installed.

I have also tried telling `gem` about the presence of libffi as follows:

`gem install ffi:1.0.7 -- --with-ldflags='-L/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib'`

Comment: I have similar problem since upgrading to Mavericks. Identical error message. Using Homebrew, I have libffi installed other native extension gems installing/removing fine. Neither of the answers to date fix this. Rather than posting a new question, raising a bounty on this one.

Comment: I suspect that the problem can be solved by passing compiler flags on gem install to point to the brew installed libffi, but I do not fully understand how or which ones.

Comment: Hebrew will confuse your computer.

Comment: Is rvm autolibs enabled?  rvm will try fetching/downloading packages via macports if it's enabled.

Comment: @rb512: Thanks, that was a good lead. I removed all traces of ffi and libffi, ran `rvm autolibs disable` after a re-start, and re-installed from scratch, but unfortunately that did not resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using rvm, and I resolved it by reinstalling the ffi gem

`gem uninstall ffi`

`gem install ffi ##or inside rails project folder run bundle install`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is best explained as a compatibility issue between Mac OS X and older versions of the ffi gem. That is why in some cases simply uninstalling and reinstalling the gem can work.

In my case ffi version *1.0.7* was specified in a project's Gemfile. My tests failed with `Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libffi.5.dylib` on that version, but if I tried latest version *1.9.3*, it installed and worked without any fuss.

I was lucky and the need for that restriction on the project was placed years ago and no longer appears to be a requirement. So in the end I moved forward with later version of ffi gem.

I suspect there may be a way to get version *1.0.7* happily installed and working on OS X 10.9.2, but I do not know what that might be.

Answer (score 1):

I have ended up in this situation after uninstalling MacPorts (I thought homebrew will be enough, but doesn't seem so). It stopped my cocoapods from updating/installing.

To make it work like a charm, I did:

```
$ sudo port install libffi
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem. Finally, I tried reinstall libffi:

```
brew reinstall libffi
```

and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

With otool and install_name_tool, you may fix the dependency problem. See [Creating working dylibs](http://osiris.laya.com/coding/dylib_linking.html) for detail.