# Rails server not starting due to weird issue (Library not loaded)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I suddenly started to have very weird problems starting rails server.

Can anyone help me?

```
 /Users/toptier/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require': dlopen(/Users/toptier/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/ffi-1.1.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libffi.5.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/toptier/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/ffi-1.1.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/toptier/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/ffi-1.1.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle
from /Users/toptier/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
from /Users/toptier/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
from /Users/toptier/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
from /Users/toptier/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/activesupport-3.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
```

Comment: Just to confirm, you are recieving this when you type "rails s" in your app directory? What version of rails are you using?

Comment: I think mean ruby 1.9.2 but what version of rails? 3.1? 3.2?

Comment: I have installed Homebrew recently, maybe that has something to do with the probelem.

Comment: Yes, sure. Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.1.8.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475287/library-not-loaded-opt-local-lib-libffi-5-dylib-but-im-using-homebrew ?

Comment: It looks like the same problem but I am confused about the answer, since it is for people who wants to compile their own dlib

Comment: I think by compiling dlib from source, it will build your dependency and solve the loadproblem. Can you try it?

Comment: I dont really know how to do it. It is not my source code, can you help me?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17316/discussion-between-sunny-juneja-and-tony)

Comment: This isn't too localized. This is a problem that happens and this question helped me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I reinstalling gem "ffi" and everything worked.

Thanks